# Employer email verification of customers receipts

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

When an employer tags certain emails as "according to our magic sauce," does that simply mean they are monitoring emails sent by employee to customers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Marking some emails important "according to our magic sauce" is something that Google does, not your employer. (Unless you work for Google, that is.)  This is one of algorithms that Google applies to the email it processes. It does not involve people reading the messages.